# Access Record record - show lock status

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I use a datasheet view of a query with aggregate sub queries attached as fields. Of course this is not editable and that is fine as its merely an overview listing of all the records along with some sum information from related tables. I have noticed that when a query is not editable the record selector lock information is not displayed. This made me wonder.

Is there is some event that can be captured to display in more or less real time when a record is locked or released by other users?

Alternatively is there any other way to display in my overview list or elsewhere what records are currently locked and if possible by what user?

Access 2010(x64)

Answer (score 1):

For an updatable query, the locked status may be displayed on the left margin as you have noted.  But that reflects record-locking by the query engine, not the same thing as whether a data result is updateable under normal circumstances.

For a read-only query, Access won't show a lock icon because in that context it isn't useful information (from most people's point of view).

You could use VBA to check the attribute of the query as a whole, and display a notification when the form is loaded.  But that doesn't relate to the record-locking icon.

`Is there is some event that can be captured to display in more or less real time when a record is locked or released by other users?`  -- I believe the simple answer is no.

Comment: I suppose i could use dsum or something like it to construct an updateable query but no doubt performance will suffer even with indexing of the relevant fields. Its unfortunate that access wont allow direct access to this status as an event. I could see some useful scenarios for that.

Answer (score -1):

Access 2007 saw the end of the JET Security model, so there is no way for you to manage user-level security in files created using 2007 or later.

The only alternative would be to use the Win API to register users by their NT ids, and to develop your own model which responded to activity. Clearly this would be no mean feat!

[Edit]

As for detecting record locks, it's possible you could implement this using an events handler class together with the ADO library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms678373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty with Class Modules (something some pundits never got to grips with), then you can [find a lead-in here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rnPiKXCRciMC&pg=PA448&lpg=PA448&dq=%22Public%20WithEvents%20rs%20As%20ADODB.Recordset%22&source=bl&ots=nwmn0ANJ8Z&sig=WqhrCyCMZ9KIAioDbtFgFHcmfAc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0fAWVO_WNMiwuASp94L4Bg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Public%20WithEvents%20rs%20As%20ADODB.Recordset%22&f=false).

Comment: I had thought about replacing the record locking in access with my own but it just seems like too much coding just to give users that convenience. If I ever have another reason too do that though I will most certainly go to town with a nice big red light green light and lock unlock symbol with text.

Comment: "is there any other way to display in my overview list or elsewhere what records are currently locked and if possible **by what user**?"
PLEASE REMOVE YOUR DONWVOTE Smandoli, and read the question

Comment: I will remove my downvote because you requested it and you seem to be angry. There's no change in my opinion. (Whoa -- S.O. informs me there has to be an edit in your answer for me to change my own vote. I didn't know that. So my vote stays the same for now.)

Comment: your answer failed to address the element of the question to which I replied, so your opinion is wrong. whether you were being annoying is besides this point.

Comment: Smandoli - the only one baiting here is you, kindly remove your down-vote and have a little dignity